# Spring validation: regex annotation does not work

Tags: regex, validation, spring-boot

When executing the controller method I receive this log:

> OBJECT: [Field error in object 'catalog' on field 'name': rejected value [**safasf**]; codes [Pattern.catalog.name,Pattern.name,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [catalog.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@5f32f731,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter$ResolvableAttribute@2180fe7e]; default message [muss auf Ausdruck "**[A-Za-z]**" passen]]

**Regex**: `[A-Za-z]`

**Input**: `safasf`

The code:

```
...
@NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=8)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z]")
    private String name;
...
```

The controller:

```
@PostMapping(ADD_CATALOG)
public String addCatalog(@Valid @ModelAttribute Catalog catalog, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        logAction("addCatalog", "Validation of "+catalog.getName()+" failed: ", result.getAllErrors().toString());
        return "redirect:/catalog/addCatalog/";
    }
    catalogProviderComponent.addOrUpdateCatalogEntity(catalogComponent.catalog2catalogEntity(catalog));
    logAction("addCatalog","catalog", catalog);
    return "redirect:/catalog/addCatalog/";
}
```

When I go to `regex101.com` everything seems to be fine. Beside that I tried few regex but none seem to work out properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To allow for one or more lowercase or uppercase letter, you should append `+` to the end of the pattern:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=1, max=8)
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z]+")
private String name;
```

Comment: What. I was some kind of 1000000% sure I tried few, including yours. Thanks... :facepalm:

Comment: Regex is an area with which many developers, even seniors ones, have surprisingly little experience using.  This applies also to things like Xpath and SQL.  Glad to be of service to you.